# material ui auto complete ID with event.target.id using onChange

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-admin

I am trying to get the id of  tag whenever onChange is fired. However the id I get from onChange function is different from the id i have used in the tag.
Here is the code:

```
<Autocomplete
 id="country"
 options={countriesList}
 classes={{
   option: classes.option,
  }}
 onChange={handleChange}
 getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.code === value.code}
 getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
 renderOption={(option) => (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    {option.label}
                                </React.Fragment>
                            )}
                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
..
..
/>

const handleChange = (event, value) => {
        console.log('ID: ', event.target.id);
         ...
         ..
}


**Output:**
country-option-0
```

"-option-0" is appending to my ID. 0 changes based on the value I select in dropdown. If I select second option in dropdwon the output will be "country-option-1"

Comment: Can u add the code to JS fiddle and share the link...

Comment: Are you using the Autocomplete from `react-admin` lib or directly from `material-ui`?

Comment: I am using auto complete from material-ui